# Establish connection to Sony DSC QX10 (Sony Camera Remote API) using AsyncUdpSocket for SSDP connection on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, sony

Yesterday I started to develop an iPhone app using the Sony Camera Remote API.

The initial step to use the WiFi camera is to establish a connection to the camera. Therefore I used the AsyncUdpSocket to start the ssdp discover using this code:

```
-(void)discoverWiFiCamera{
self.ssdpSock = [[AsyncUdpSocket alloc] initIPv4];
[self.ssdpSock setDelegate:self];
[self.ssdpSock enableBroadcast:TRUE error:nil];

NSError *socketError = nil;
if (![self.ssdpSock bindToPort:1900 error:&socketError]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed binding socket: %@", [socketError localizedDescription]);
}
if(![self.ssdpSock joinMulticastGroup:@"239.255.255.250" error:&socketError]){
    NSLog(@"Failed joining multicast group: %@", [socketError localizedDescription]);
}
if (![self.ssdpSock enableBroadcast:TRUE error:&socketError]){
    NSLog(@"Failed enabling broadcast: %@", [socketError localizedDescription]);
}

[self.ssdpSock sendData:[@"M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nMX: 1\r\nST: urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                 toHost:@"239.255.255.250" port:1900 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
[self.ssdpSock receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(completeSearch:) userInfo:self repeats:NO];
}

- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port{
NSLog(@"%s %ld %@ %d",__FUNCTION__,tag,host,port);
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"\r\n%@",aStr);

return YES;
}
```

As it appears, the app is able to establish a connection to the camera (Sony DSC QX10). Therefore, a response from the host (IP address: 10.29.57.38) is received by the iPhone (IP address: 10.0.1.1). However, the response data is exactly the same as the sent data.

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
MX: 1
ST: urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1
```

Therefore, I'd like to ask, if anybody of you already experiences the same behavior of the Sony Camera API or the AsnycUdpSocket?

Thanks,
Josef

Comment: What you're seeing is in fact the message you sent. I have the same issue and found out (with some UDP sniffing) that Sony's own app doesn't use the SSDP discovery method. They just connect to the address 10.0.0.1/sony/camera on which the QX10 is available. I've tried it myself and was able to reach the camera on that address. As the SampleApp of Sony isn't even able to find the QX10 I believe that the SSDP discovery doesn't even work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also tested the SampleApp which is obviously not working (are they even testing their own SampleApp?). Connecting to the address 10.0.0.1/sony/camera works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember ssdp:discover message is a mulitcast message, sent to every interface on that subnet. If the message is same, you might be reading your own message being sent out.

Additional Resources: 
Camera Remote API Development Guide Doc has service discovery Request/Response example.
UPnP SSDP service discovery examples on the web.

Also when I see the IP addresses you mentioned, could you double-check your iPhone is connecting to QX-10 acting as WiFi Access Point. I would expect QX10 to have IP address like 10.0.1.1.

Best Regards,
Prem

Comment: That makes sense. I already wondered why the iPhone seemed to operate as the server (using IP address 10.0.0.1). Seems like my iPhone does display an incorrect IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I solved it by using the bindToAddress:port: method instead of the bindToPort method.